# How to set duration of android mediaPlayer on start activity

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

I need help to set duration of `MediaPlayer` on start activity.

I have tried using `seekTo()` but its not working correctly.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
protected void Player(String bURL, int seekTo){
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playpauseBtn);
    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(bURL);
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    if (seekTo != 0) {
                        mediaPlayer.seekTo(seekTo);
                    }
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean you want to seek to some position?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Exactly i wan to seek to some position.

Answer (score 1):

Try to modify to this:

```
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            if (!mp.isPlaying()) {
                if (seekTo != 0) {
                   mp.seekTo(seekTo);
                }
                mp.start();
            }

        }
    });
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(bURL);
mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

Comment: I did this way but MediaPlayer started from 0.

Comment: Log out seekTo value probably it value is 0

Comment: The value I'm trying to assign is in milliseconds like 7500, I was wondering if i have event who can be triggered when mediaPlayer started, then I think it will work fine.

Comment: It should work at is, I use it successfully. Maybe put in question the whole code include the "seekTo" assignment. BTW the line this.mediaPlayer = mediaPlayer;
 is redundant.

Comment: I just updated the question, Basically i made a function where i pass just audio file url and seekTo values in milliseconds.

Comment: Try to register the listener before. What is the kind of file you playing?